# События внутри тэгов

Tags: javascript, pure_js

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, обязательно ли при написании кода JavaScript, события прописывать внутри тегов, или же можно это сделать внутри файла JS?

Если  да, то каким образом?

Comment: Мало того, обязательно выносить. Посмотрите гуугле jquery селекторы.

Comment: Я имею ввиду изучение чистого js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Даже для чистого js лучше их вынести.

Формат такой(или около того)

```
<div id="someDiv">press for Action</div>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var somediv = document.getElementById('someDiv');
somediv.onclick = function(){
  alert('Action');
}
</script>
```

Comment: function $(id)
    {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    
    //var somediv = document.getElementById('someDiv'); и таких еще N штук в мусор
    
    $('someDiv').onclick = function()
    {
      alert('Action');
    }

Comment: Самый умный, да? =))) *по доброму*
+1

Comment: все для удобства и избавления насильства фантазии по выдумыванию десятков переменных)

Comment: Отличный совет. Спасибо.

Comment: @Palmervan, @knes, а для классов и простых элементов без id и class, возможно также сделать?

Comment: естественно:

    function $(selector)
    {
      var prefix = selector[0];
      selector = selector.substring(1);
      switch(prefix){
        case '#': return document.getElementById(selector);
        case '.': return document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
        default: return document.getElementsByTagName(prefix + selector);
      }
    }

использование:

    $('#id') == document.getElementById('id')
    $('.class') == document.getElementsByClassName('class')
    $('tag') == document.getElementsByTagName('tag')